# in IE7, my containing div doesn't expand to the contents of that div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

My Code: http://jsfiddle.net/GY5Dg/2/

So, the containing div, #facebox, expands to the content in all browsers except IE7.

So, what do I need to do to get IE7 to behave the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `width:370px` from `#facebox .content`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/GY5Dg/3/

Comment: tahnks, guess I've just been staring at it too long.